# giving axis ticks more space in nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am constructing a horizontal bar plot in `nvd3` with domain names as x-labels. The domain names, while not too long, are longer than the amount of space given to them. How do I increase the amount of space given to an axis in `nvd3`?

[jsfiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fZnDg/4/)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you can specify your own margins. For example:

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
    .margin({top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 90}) // increase the left margin
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; });
```

Here is the [updated fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZnDg/13/).